Fb business Feature unavailable Facebook Login is currently unavailable for this app or ErrorUtils caught an error: Minified invariant #21945;
While I'm trying to integrate facebook business with our platform, when I try login with my account which has access to the developer application, it logged in successfully. but when I'm trying to test with other account for testing I got this message from facebook "Feature unavailable Facebook Login is currently unavailable for this app as we are updating additional details for this app. Please try again later".
although I add the config_id. After some search I found that I should verify the application to as I need Advanced Access yo public_profile So I tried from other app in my company which is verified and got this empty screen 
with this error in the console ErrorUtils caught an error: Minified invariant #21945;
